# Typescript - get rid of boilerplate from my functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 functions which modifies lists. That lists are fields of an object. This object has a lot of lists and I don't want to write the same code few times. I need reusable function.

Now that looks like below:

```
setLists(): void {
  if (this.product.orders !== null) {
    this.orders = this.product.orders.join(', '); 
  } else {
    this.orders = '';
  }

  if (this.product.relatedProducts !== null) {
    this.relatedProducts = this.product.relatedProducts.join(', '); 
  } else {
    this.relatedProducts = '';
  }
}
```

Here are only 2 fields but in fact product has many lists. I don't want to repeat the same operation for each list.

Second boilerplate function looks like below:

```
updateProductLists(): void {
  let splittedOrders: string[] = this.orders.split(",");
  splittedOrders = splittedOrders.map(o => o.trim());
  this.product.orders = new Array<string>();
  this.project.orders.push(...splittedOrders);

  let splittedRelatedProducts: string[] = this.relatedProducts.split(",");
  splittedRelatedProducts = splittedRelatedProducts.map(r => r.trim());
  this.product.relatedProducts = new Array<string>();
  this.product.relatedProducts.push(...splittedRelatedProducts);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are an example of how you can create the two more generic functions `listToString` and `stringToList` and how you can use them in your code instead of writing the same thing over and over

```
// Your old method will now look like this
setLists(): void {
    this.orders = this.listToString(this.product.orders);
    this.relatedProducts = this.listToString(this.product.relatedProducts);
}

// Generic method for joining the arrays into strings the way you did
listToString(sourceList: any[]): string {
    return sourceList ? sourceList.join(', ') : '';
}

// Your old method will now look like this
updateProductLists(): void {
    this.product.orders = this.stringToList(this.orders);
    this.product.relatedProducts = this.stringToList(this.relatedProducts);
}

// Generic method for splitting the strings into lists the way you did
stringToList(sourceString: string): any[] {
    return sourceString.split(',').map(i => i.trim());
}
```

Comment: Note: if the attributes of the object are typed (which they should be in TypeScript, but don't appear to be judging from the question) I believe there would be a problem trying to assign the value of a string to a variable that was previously an array (and vice versa).

Comment: @Vintr where do you see the same variable being used for both string and array values? Could it be that you are mixing `this.relatedProducts` with `this.product.relatedProducts`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed I am. Such confusing naming. :)

Comment: @Vintr indeed haha :)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said: you should write a generic function that takes a list of any kind and performs the logic on it. Then you put all your lists in an array and iterate over it with the function you wrote. Example:

```
function stringifyArray(array: any[], separator: string): string {
  if (!array) { // Checks for undefined, null, NaN, 0, empty string
    return '';
  }
  return array.join(separator);
}

const oldLists: any[][] = [
  this.orders,
  this.relatedproducts
]

const newLists: string[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < oldLists.length; i++) {
  newLists.push(stringifyArray(oldLists[i], ','));
}
```

Figure out how to define generic functions for the rest of the actions you need to perform, then loop over your lists in the same way.

By the way, it might be a good idea to have separate fields for your lists and their stringified versions. That way you might not have to convert back and forth so much.

Also note that the function in my example is actually redundant, as it duplicates the behavior already present in `Array.prototype.join()`. The non-redundant code would be:

```
const oldLists: any[][] = [
  this.orders,
  this.relatedproducts
]

const newLists: string[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < oldLists.length; i++) {
  newLists.push(oldLists[i].join(','));
}
```